# How to reload a data table from a Controller? (I'm using Core Data)

Tags: ios, core-data

I am currently developing an iOS app. I am trying to fetch data from a table just after insert the data on table. This is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Notification *notification = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if ([notification.isRead isEqualToNumber:@NO]) {
    [self sendNotificationData:notification];
    notification.isRead = @YES;
  }

  [self insertPost:notification.notificatableId];

  Post *post = [self fetchObjectfrom:@"Post"
                       withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId == %@", notification.notificatableId]];
}

- (void)insertPost:(NSString *)postId
{

  NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:postId, @"notification[post_id]", nil];

  [[AkdemiaAPIClient sharedClient] POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/notifications/%@/get_post",postId] parameters:parameters
                            success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON) {

                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                                                      forKey:@"PostNotificationsDetailsNotificationName"];
                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PostNotificationsDetailsSucceedNotificationName"
                                                                                  object:nil];

                              AkdemiaSyncEngine *syncEngine = [[AkdemiaSyncEngine alloc] init];
                              [syncEngine processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData:JSON forComponent:kFeed];

                              [[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
                              [[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];

                            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PostNotificationsDetailsErrorNotificationName"
                                                                                  object:nil];

                            }];
}
```

The problem is when I select a **notification** and try to fetch the **post** immediately ***after to insert***, because it seems like isn't on this table, but if I refresh the controller and select the same **notification** then the **post** exists and everything is ok.

I was trying to find something like:

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

but that works on a request instead of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods. In the callback from your API call you can insert the retrieved items in Core Data and save. The delegate methods should then be called and insert / update / delete table view cells based on the `indexPath`. There is a reference implementation in the Xcode template (Master-Detail, check Core Data).

Comment: That isn't work for me because I am handling two different types of objects notifications and posts, then I already have a `NSFetchedResultsController` for notifications and I created another for posts, when I try to looking for the post (in the `NSFetchedResultsController` for posts) based on the `indexPath` dismatch with the ìndexPath` in the `NSFetchedResultsController` for notifications (`self.fetchedResultsController`). I want to know if it's possible to looking for in a ´NSFetchedResultsController´ based on object's attributes